# CKEditor template plugin window content empty

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am having a weird issue. Whenever I am clicking on the CKEditor template button, the template window opens without anty content. The issue seems to be with my set up as this is working fine in CKEditor samples.But I am unable to figure out the cause as there is no error in console and firebug. Anybody faced this issue before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ffP2K/1/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/ffP2K/1/show/

I hope you have got the correct script reference rest below sample should help.

Please let me know if I missed anything.

Good Link: http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery

Hope this helps,

**script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ckeditor.com//apps/ckeditor/3.5.2/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

**Code**

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );


$('#click').click(function(){
    // Find outer div
    var div = document.getElementById('outer');

    // Get value from height textbox
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;


    // Uses jQuery framework to set the height of the div
    $(div).css('height', height + 'px');

    // Tells CKEDITOR to resize to the desired height, and width
    editor.resize($(div).width(),height);
    return false;
})

​
```

**working Image**

[image]